# best way to display value from mysql inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I haven't been coding for a while, and i started a new project lately.
In that project, i need to make a very simple inner join to associate values from 2 tables:

table questions:

```
 id  |  question  |  order
 1   |  how?      |  1
 2   |  what?     |  2
 3   |  when?     |  3
```

table answers:

```
 id_question  |  answer    |  order
 1            |  this way  |  1
 1            |  that way  |  2
 2            |  this      |  1
 2            |  that      |  2
 3            |  now       |  1
 3            |  later     |  2
```

How can I correctly get the questions and related answers, and display them, ordered by order?

I did this:

```
SELECT id, question, Q.order as qorder, id_question, answer, A.order as aorder FROM questions as Q INNER JOIN answers as A ON Q.id = A.id_question ORDER BY qorder
```

which result in this:

```
 id  |  question  |  qorder  | id_question  |  answer    |  aorder
 1   |  how?      |  1       | 1            |  this way  |  1
 1   |  how?      |  1       | 1            |  that way  |  2
 2   |  what?     |  2       | 2            |  this      |  1
 2   |  what?     |  2       | 2            |  that      |  2
 3   |  when?     |  3       | 3            |  now       |  1
 3   |  when?     |  3       | 3            |  later     |  2
```

DISPLAYING RESULTS:

```
$same_id = -1;
while ( $poll = $qa -> fetch() ) {
   if ($poll['id'] == $same_id ) { 
      echo '<li>'.$poll['answer'].'</li>';
   }
   else {
      if ( $poll['id'] == $same_id+1 ) { echo '</ul>'; }
      echo '<ul>'.$poll['question'];
      echo '<li>'.$poll['answer'].'</li>';
      $same_id = $poll['id'];
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

which display:

```
<ul>How?
<li>this way</li>
<li>that way</li>
</ul>

<ul>What?
<li>this</li>
<li>that</li>
</ul>

<ul>When?
<li>now</li>
<li>later</li>
</ul>
```

**it all works out, but it doesn't feel right.**

**First**, I have the answers ordered by "luck", without specifying it in the request.

**And then**, the code feels too "complicated" for what it is.

I feel there is a better and cleaner way to do this kind of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `aorder` to order explicitly:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
INNER JOIN ...
ORDER BY
    qorder ASC,
    aorder ASC
```

Your code to display is alright. It could be improved by using [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and `foreach`, but this is personal taste/preference.

```
$polls = $qa->fetchAll();
foreach($polls as $poll) {
    // output question and answers
}
```

Comment: Ok then, thanks, I never though you could give 2 parameters to ORDER BY.
But isn't it a bit "faster" to show the results while fetch ? Instead of saving them in an array and outputing the results right after?

Comment: I strongly assume that the `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` is quite fast (otherwise it wouldn't have been implemented). But you can manually check it by comparing `PDOStatement::fetch()` with `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`.